# Call in C++ Destructor Fails

Tags: c++, odbc, destructor

I have this code:

```
DManag::~DManag() {

    printf("in dest\n");
    if(mainConn.IsOpen()) {
        printf("about to close\n");
        mainConn.Close();
        printf("closed!\n");
    }
    printf("end dest\n");

}
```

The output is: `in dest \n about to close \n` and that is it.

It (mainConn -> CDatabase class) seems to silently fail upon calling close(). I know you are supposed to close connections as soon as you are done with them. But I inherited this code from someone else, but the program does not provide an easy way to close the connection at the right time. Close() and open() calls are located in `afxdb.h`.

Any idea why it might fail like this? Thanks!

Comment: Can `mainConn.Close()` throw any exceptions?

Comment: @hmjd Part of Windows API, and it is a little older package (ODBC). Did not say anything about exceptions in the documentation, it is a little lacking. I'll look again... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/5k2d6k87(v=vs.80).aspx Doesn't say anything about exceptions.

Comment: If you put a break point in the code and step through it, what happens? Is the print statement executing? Is it possibly a problem that the output is simply not being flushed before the program exits?

Comment: In that case suggest, for investigative purposes: `try { mainConn.Close(); } catch (...) { printf("exception\n"); }` to check for exceptions.

Comment: @lefticus I tried printing to a file too, but I guess that might encounter the same problem (not flushing). I'll try a breakpoint. Thanks.

Comment: @hmjd Doesn't throw anything. :' ( I'll try breakpoints, see if it is flushing the output.

Comment: Use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` instead of `printf()`. `stderr` is unbuffered.

Comment: @hmjd, Same result. Thanks anyways. I'm running out of ideas. -_-

Comment: What is the scope of the instance of `DManag`? Specifically, is the destructor invoked after `main()` exits? I am unsure of the state of `stdout` and `stderr` after `main()` exits.

Comment: Is your DManag object in global scope. Is the object `mainConn` a global? If so you could be falling foul of the order of destruction of global variables.

Comment: @LokiAstari mainConn is global. So you are saying that I am calling Close() on an object already deleted? mainConn.IsOpen() runs fine though.

Comment: @skynorth: Potentially. Just because something seems to work does not mean it is being done correctly (it might just be an accident). Trying moving both objects into main() so that you can guarantee the order of creation/destruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `CDatabase::Close` is throwing an exception and causing the rest of the destructor to be bypassed.   The documentation doesn't mention this method can throw but other usage samples on the internet indicate that it can.

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/readdb.aspx
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/211232-cdatabaseopenex-fails-without-exception-in-release-mode/

Try modifying the destructor as follows

```
DManag::~DManag() {
    printf("in dest\n");
    if(mainConn.IsOpen()) {
        printf("about to close\n");
        try {
          mainConn.Close();
        } catch (CDBException&) {
          print("exception occurred\n");
        }
        printf("closed!\n");
    }
    printf("end dest\n");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception unfortunately. I even tried catch (...).

Comment: @skynorth have you attached a debugger and seen if it's crashing on an Av?

Comment: @skynorth AV = access violation. I would attach a debugger to the DTOR, set the debugger to break on access violation and stack overflow and then step through. It's very likely the cause of the problem